# NoReverseMatch at display/success/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In the get_success_URL method of FileView , i used 'display:redirect' as the URL to be redirected . But i am getting an error as

```
Reverse for 'redirect' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 15}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['display/success/']
```

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/display/upload/
Django Version:     1.10.dev20160512164014
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Am I missing something?

**display/views.py**

```
class FileView(FormView):

    template_name = 'display/upload.html'
    form_class = FileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        file_upload = FileModel(file=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['file'])
        file_upload.save()
        self.id = file_upload.id

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('display:redirect', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

def redirect(request):

    return render(request,"display/success.html")
```

**display/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from . import views

from display.views import FileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^start/', views.initial,name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/',FileView.as_view(),name='upload'),
    url(r'^success/',views.redirect,name='redirect'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
Reverse for 'redirect' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 15}' not found.
```

The error message is telling you what's wrong. You've passed a keyword argument and when it tries to reverse / find the url it doesn't because you have the url specified as:

```
url(r'^success/',views.redirect,name='redirect')
```

Which doesn't accept any arguments. One possibility is to make your url into this:

```
^success/(?P<pk>\d+)/$
```